# Почему бинарные файлы созданные разными языками программирования различаются?

Tags: java, c++

Например, мои коды на языках программирования Java и C++ дают разные бинарные файлы.

Код на C++:

```
char fileName[100];
cin >> fileName;
int N;
cin >> N;
ofstream file(fileName, ios::binary);
for (int i = 2, j = 1; j <= N; i += 2, j++)
    file.write( reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i), sizeof(i) );
file.close();
```

Код на Java:

```
RandomAccessFile ra = new RandomAccessFile(scanner.nextLine(), "rw");
int limit = scanner.nextInt();
int number = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    ra.writeInt(number);
    number += 2;
}
ra.close();
```

Задача:
**Дано имя файла и целое число N (> 1). Создать файл целых чисел с данным именем и записать в него N первых положительных четных чисел (2, 4, …).**

Может они используют разные алгоритмы?

---

Бинарный файл, я имею ввиду не исполняемый файл, а файл данных. То есть, [двоичные файлы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB)

Comment: Напишите чем файлы отличаются при N=1 и 2.

Comment: При N=2: Внутри каждого файла должны лежать числа: 2 и 4 в бинарном формате. Но почему то checksum результирующих файлов различаются

Answer (score 19):

Начнем с Java - описание метода:

> The `java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeInt(int v)` method writes an int to the file as four bytes, high byte first.

То есть всегда пишет в файл 4 байта старшим байтом вперед - такое представление называют BigEndian. Java - платформонезависимый язык, поэтому на любой платформе Вы получите одинаковый результат.

А вот с C++ все гораздо интереснее -  `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&i)` - преобразует int в массив из 4х байт в последовательности, которая зависит от платформы BigEndian или LittleEndian. Поэтому даже один и тот же код на разных платформах будет выдавать разный результат. (архитектура x86 имеет порядок LittleEndian)

Comment: вроде же little endian это наоборот когда старший байт последним идет

Comment: Да, а ошибся. Поправил ответ.